# GWT fileupload, file not being sent in the POST

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, gwtupload

I am struggling with a simple file uploading using GWT 2.4 + gwtupload 0.6.4 library.

Here is the relevant part of my dialog ui.xml:

```
<g:DialogBox modal="true" width="400px" height="150px">
        <g:caption><ui:msg>Import new..</ui:msg></g:caption>
        <g:VerticalPanel styleName="full-width">
            <g:InlineLabel styleName="formlabel"><ui:msg>File name</ui:msg></g:InlineLabel>
            <up:Uploader ui:field="uploader" validExtensions="zip" styleName="uploader full-width">
            </up:Uploader>
            <g:Button styleName="button" ui:field="importButton" enabled="true">
                <ui:msg>Import</ui:msg>
            </g:Button>
```

The `importButton` calls `uploader.submit()` eventually. My problem is that the first time I press the button, and empty POST is being sent to the server and I get back an error message. If I press the button second time, my file is being POST-ed well. If I close the dialog and start over the very same thing happens. Every import attempt following the first one is OK.

Here is the empty POST example:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
boundary=---------------------------9003259118762
Content-Length: 46 -----------------------------9003259118762--
```

I tried to click a second time on the button as a workaround. However if I catch the error message received and call `uploader.submit()` again or call it even from a `Timer()` callback it is not working as when I click with the mouse the second time.

Do you have any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: you should probably add the way you instantiate the uploader. Is auto-submit enabled? What input type is chosen, etc...

Comment: Hi! UI binder instantiates the Uploader and auto submit is disabled

Comment: No idea of what's wrong then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that some lines after `uploader.submit()` there was a `uploader.setEnabled(false)` invocation. After removing it the uploader started to work normally.. :-)